# Struts2 - How can I use <s:a> without previously knowing the action that I'll use?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I have to display several links in a JSP and the structure of the HTML is the equal for every link, so I've used an struts2 taglib iterator to build it. The problem is that I don't know how to build the link itself:

**My JSP**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<head></head>
<div class="menuBotoes">
    <s:iterator value="links" var="link">
        <s:a namespace="link.nameSpace" action="link.action">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableBotaoMenu">
                <tr class="trCimaBotaoMenuSelect">
                    <td align="center" class="imagemBotaoMenuSelect"><img src="<s:url value="/includes/imagens/global/botoes/grafico.png" />" /></td>
                    <td align="left" class="descricaoBotaoMenuSelect"><s:property value="textoLink" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="trBaixoBotaoMenuSelect">
                    <td align="center" class="imagemBotaoMenuSelect" colspan="2"><s:property value="projeto" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </s:a>
    </s:iterator>
</div>
```

**The object that is being iterated over in the JSP is this:**

```
public enum LinksRelatorios {

    1("Caixa Visita", "/relatorios/", "iniciarRelatorioCaixaVisita", "TISS"),
    2("Caixa Visita Empresa", "/relatorios/", "iniciarRelatorioCaixaVisitaEmpresa", "TISS"),
    3("Produtividade Internação Domiciliar", "/relatorios/", "iniciarRelatorioInternacaoDomiciliar", "TISS"),
    4("Pendências", "/relatorios/", "iniciarRelatorioPendencias", "TISS"),
    5("Solicitação Inicial", "/relatorios/", "iniciarRelatorioSolicitacaoInicial", "TISS"),
    6("Solicitação Prorrogação", "/relatorios/", "iniciarRelatorioSolicitacaoProrrogacao", "TISS"),
    7("Tempo Resposta", "/relatorios/", "iniciarRelatorioTempoResposta", "TISS");

    private String textoLink;
    private String nameSpace;
    private String action;
    private String projeto;

    private LinksRelatorios(final String textoLinkParam, final String nameSpaceParam, final String actionParam,
            final String projetoParam) {
        this.textoLink = textoLinkParam;
        this.nameSpace = nameSpaceParam;
        this.action = actionParam;
        this.projeto = projetoParam;
    }

    public String getTextoLink() {
        return this.textoLink;
    }

    public String getNameSpace() {
        return this.nameSpace;
    }

    public String getAction() {
        return this.action;
    }

    public String getProjeto() {
        return this.projeto;
    }
}
```

**My Action**

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
public class InicioAction extends BaseAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1161409943678292285L;

    private static final LinksRelatorios[] links = LinksRelatorios.values();

    public String inicio() {
        this.addActionMessage(this.getText("msg.sucesso.saudacao.mensagem", new String[] { (String) BaseAction
                .getSession().getAttribute(Constantes.PERFIL) }));
        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }

    public String iniciarRelatoriosPorProjeto() {
        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }

    public String iniciarRelatoriosFiltro() {
        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }

    public static LinksRelatorios[] getLinks() {
        return InicioAction.links;
    }
}
```

I've tried using 
`<s:a namespace="link.nameSpace" action="link.action">`, `< s:a namespace="%{link.nameSpace}" action="%{link.action}">`, `<s:a namespace="#link.nameSpace" action="#link.action">`, but not seems to work.

Before someone asks, the enum is working fine, in my JSP I have `<s:property value="projeto" />` and `<s:property value="textoLink" />` and these are properties that come from the enum.

I've read the online official docs in http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/using-struts-2-tags.html, http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/a.html and http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/url.html but the examples sections is actually pretty poor comparing to frameworks such as PrimeFaces or RichFaces that have built theirs own showcases.

Comment: try using <s:a namespace="%{#link.nameSpace}" action="%{#link.action}">

Comment: Please, post your comment as an answer so I can accept it as the answer for my question. It would be nice if you could explain the syntax too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code

```
<s:a namespace="%{#link.nameSpace}" action="%{#link.action}">
```

Use of %{} makes struts2 evaluate the contents of the expression inside {} and then assign the result to the attribute.

Refer http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/tag-syntax.html for more details.